# I want to change my current 15 amp split outlet to a 20 amp Can I use a pigtail on the red and black ( at both ends) to do this?

Tags: electrical

I have a 14/3 15 amp split plug that I want to change to a 20 amp GFI. Can I use a pigtail on the red and black to do this.

Comment: What voltage do you measure between the two hot prongs on the outlet?

Comment: **What loads do you plan to plug in here?** There may be other ways to solve your challenge.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot do this.  The reason it's a 15A circuit is that it's wired with 14 ga. wire.  For a 20A circuit it generally takes 12 ga. wire.  So just changing out the plug does nothing but create a dangerous situation.

If you need a 20A GFCI-protected circuit the best and correct approach is to pull a new 12 ga. wire from a new GFCI breaker in the panel.

Comment: Agree with jwh20 14-2 or 3 or 20 if there was such a thing is limited to a 15 amp circuit breaker, can’t believe the other 2 that I thought were pros asks more questions , 14 awg wire is limited to 15 amp outlets !  +